# How to find form in jQuery HTML variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script which returns the original HTML of the current page, which has a form on it:

```
var orignalHTML = ""; 

$.get(document.location.href, function(data) {
    originalHTML = data;
});
```

What I'd now like to do, is find any FORM elemnts in this 'originalHTML' variable. I've tried the following, but it returns nothing:

```
$(originalHTML).find("form")
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

As a heads up. I know there's an easier method, that would involve just querying the current page, but I'm looking for any mismatches between forms in the original HTML and the current page.

I also know that there are complexities around synchronicity, but this is about accessing the `<form>` field, not about when the variable is populated.

Thank you

Comment: Is the `.find()` code inside the callback function of `$.get`?

Comment: @Barmar it isn't, but I've tested it in the callback too.

Comment: If the `<form>` is the root element of `originalHTML` you'll need to use `filter()` instead of `find()`

Comment: Then it's trying to use `originalHTML` before the callback function updates the variable. Anything that depends on the AJAX call has to be in the callback.

Comment: As Barmar pointed out, it must be in the callback, or it could (probably will) execute before the page form has loaded.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan your solution works!

Comment: `filter` won't find it if it's nested further down. You can use `$("<div>", {html: originalHTML})` to make it work in both cases.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I don't fully understand how that fits in. Like this...? `$("<div>", {html: originalHTML}).filter("form")`

Comment: `$("<div>", {html: originalHTML}).find("form")`

Comment: Great, thank you so much @Barmar!

Comment: how about using [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?: `$('body').load(document.location.href + ' form')`